Determine horizontal FOV of a panoramic photo
Say I have a panoramic photo (less than 360) and would like to view it in a cylindrical screen in a VR headset to get an immersive experience. How to determine the optimal width and height of the screen that reproduces a natural-looking perspective (assuming the viewer is at the center of the curvature, with a radius of 2m)?
Another way to ask the question is how to determine the horizontal FOV of a panoramic photo?


What kind of projection?  A typical setup for a perspective projection is to set the Vertical FOV at about 60 degree's. And let the Horizontal FOV vary based on the aspect ratio. 21:9 ends up around 110 degree's horizontal. More then 110 and perspective projections start to distort at the edges a fair bit. In the example image shown in the question the far right and left sides of the image are stretching out and distorting while the center isn't. That is typical of a wide field of view. Especially with perspective projections.
